# Perl expressions in command line - renaming files

Tags: perl, shell, rename, local-variables

Could anyone explain the occurence of `our`?

```
ls -1 | grep .ppm | xargs rename -n 's/.*/our $i; if(!$i) { $i=1; } sprintf("%03d.jpg", $i++)/e'
```

I tried changing `our` anything else, (`opti`, here),

```
ls -1 | grep .ppm | xargs rename -n 's/.*/opti $i; if(!$i) { $i=1; } sprintf("%03d.jpg", $i++)/e'
```

throws following error:

```
 Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at (user-supplied code).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is apparently compiled within scope of `use strict;`. This, among other things, enforces the declaration of variables.

Variables are commonly declared using `my`, making them lexical variables. A lexical variable only exists until the end of the curly braces in which the variable is declared, or until the end of the replacement "expression" in this case.

Much more rarely, variables are declared using `our`. This makes them package variables. These continue to exist even when the current lexical scope is exited. This allows `$i` to keep its value between invocations of the replacement expression.

---

By the way,

```
s/.*/our $i; if(!$i) { $i=1; } sprintf("%03d.jpg", $i++)/e
```

could be shortened to

```
s/.*/our $i; sprintf("%03d.jpg", ++$i)/e
```

or even

```
s/.*/sprintf("%03d.jpg", ++(our $i))/e
```

or even

```
s/.*/sprintf("%03d.jpg", ++$::i)/e
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's allowing you to reuse the global variable `$i` in the scope of the current renaming operation.

If it is not yet defined (i.e. the first file), `$i` is set to `1`.

The `$i++` used as an argument to `sprintf` means that for every file that is processed, the value of `$i` increases.

See [`our` in the perl docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) for a full description. The key here is that each rename is happening within a loop, so `our` is needed to make the definition global to the whole script, rather than local to within the loop. This means that means that the same variable is shared between iteration of the loop, so the counter isn't reset each time.